# Page resize fails after updating dom content dynamically

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm developing a mobile application using jqm and phonegap.
I've created a multi-page html file. There are two jqm pages with ids 'myPage1' and 'myPage2' inside single html file.'myPage1' contains a list of items.On click of list item i've to issue an ajax call and show the response data on 'myPage2'.
After getting response from ajax call i'm calling jqm changePage function like:

$.mobile.changePage('#myPage2', {
            transition : "slide",
            reverse : false,
            changeHash : true
});

On pagecreate event i'm making some changes in DOM which causes page display size to increase. Everything works perfectly fine on pc browser but on android the page size remains same as screen size i.e. i cannot scroll down to see full page content.

I've tried calling $('#myPage2').page() and $(document).resize() after updating DOM but all in vain.

The problem only occurs when changing page using jqm ajax based page loading. If i create a separate html file, declare 'myPage2' in it and instead of calling $.mobile.changePage, use rel='external' as link attribute in 'myPage1' list item, the problem resolves. I don't even have to call $('#myPage2').page().

But i want to use jqm Ajax based page loading as i want to leverage jqm page transitions.

Following are my config details:
Jquery verison - 1.6.2
Jquery Mobile Version - 1.0 Beta 2
Android version - 2.2.2
Android Browser : Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2.2; hd-us; eeepc Build/FRG83G) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1

Any pointer would be really helpful as my work is gated due to this.
Thanks in advance.

Ajay

Comment: Please accept the answer that suits _this_ question the most, and then ask another if you have an additional question. Stack Overflow is not a forum, it's a place where individual questions receive peer reviewed answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `.resize();` or `.page();` try the new trigger option:

```
.trigger('create');
```

Here are the release notes for Beta2:

- http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/08/03/jquery-mobile-beta-2-released/

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. I tried $('#myPage2').trigger('create') as suggested by you but it did not helped. I commented out all my code that updates dom and tried to load a static html page via mobile.changepage. To my surprise the problem still persists even though i'm not at all touching DOM. The problem only occurs with jqm ajax based loading. Disabling Ajax with rel='external' resolves the issue. Any more suggestions please.

Comment: One more thing, I'm testing it on galaxy tab emulator. Will get a real device soon to check if the problem is emulator specific.

Comment: Just observed a strange thing.
My issue resolves if i include jqm css in my html via link i.e.

<link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.css" />

But it comes back if i include css from my resources like:

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.css" type="text/css"/>

Please note that jqm css in my resources have the same content as the above link.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: naming convention? try naming the files the same name instead of jquery.mobile.css

Comment: Phill.. Man, you're rockstar. Renaming file to same name did the trick.

Comment: Please broaden my horizons though. How did it worked. The reason i renamed the file is that if in future i've to update jqm, then i do not have to rename css and js files in all my html files. Updating the css and js content will do the job. I still don't understand that if i want to use a css file, why i cannot rename it. I'm under impression that file name has nothing to do with the content inside.